# How can I reset selenium mouse position with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

when I use selenium to click element by position with python

1: I can through `find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='close']").click()`

to colse some tips
2. I use this ActionChains to click element by code

```
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(x_pos, y_pos))
action.click()
action.perform()
```

but not clicked, I think mouse position have changed buy using fisrt click, and How can I reset mouse position to (0,0) or have mouse position reset method?

Comment: _...I think mouse position have changed..._ why do you think so?

Comment: I believe the click will move to the middle of the element you are clicking on....   The move is relative to the current element (middle?), or 0,0 if no element is active.

Comment: @DebanjanB when I find elemnt with "//div[@class='close']", I record this element location as l_pos, and then use follow code, click have effect.      action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset( -l_pos['x'], -l_pos['y']))                  
action.move_by_offset(x_pos, y_pos))
action.click()
action.perform()

Comment: I have used Interim programme: add this code follow action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)            element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    s_x, s_y = element.size['width'], element.size['height']
    action.move_to_element(element)
    action.move_by_offset(-s_x/2, -s_y/2)

Comment: the offets will be relative to the current element.  (I think it's relative to the center of the element, but it's possible it's top/left of the current element...)  What is it you are trying to do by moving the location of the click?  Or are you trying to click on the <body>?

Comment: btw, Selenium isn't actually moving the cursor... it's generating events.

Comment: @pcalkins I just want to create a click_position(x_coordinate, y_coordinate) function, which can through coordinate click window

Comment: I would select the <body> then use offsets on the element.  It'll be relative to top/left of body... however, I don't think this will do much unless there are event handlers on the body.